# Date table column will be active when other table column in the same table will changes in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Table Data

```
    |companyId|
    |companyName|
    |City|
    |email|
    |status|
    |date=>timestamp|
```

What I want, when I insert data in  "status" column "date" column automatically timestamp otherwise empty. Now data is showing "0000-00-00 00:00:00" if "status" column is empty.
I can do it manually if I remove the timestamp from the date field and manually insert data.

My code I am including

My PHP Code

```
<table id="exbio" class="display table table-striped table-bordered" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" width="" style="font-size:small;">

                        <tbody>
                                        <?php 
                                                $data1 = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT company.companyID,company.CompanyName,company.Website,company.State,company.City,company.Employee,company.Revenue,company.Country,company.Phone,company.Status,company.Date FROM company WHERE company.scat_id="40"');       
                                                while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($data1)) {
                                        ?>  


                                <tr>                               
                                        <td><?php echo "<a href=\"healthdetails.php?id={$row3['companyID']}\">{$row3['CompanyName']}</a>";?></td>                                     
                                        <td><?php echo $row3['City']; ?></td>                                       
                                        <td><?php echo $row3['Email']; ?></td>
                                        <td><a class="" href="<?php echo empty($row3['Status'])?"": $row3['Status']?>">
                        <?php if($row3['Status']!=''){ echo '<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
                                        }else{echo '';} ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $row3['Date'];?></td> 
                                 </tr>      
                                <?php
                                        }                                               
                                ?>
                        </tbody>
                </table>
```

Any Help?

Comment: You don't `insert` data into a `column` you do an `update`. Why not just update the date column as well? Other than that I think you'll have to use a trigger, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/triggers.html.

Comment: I can do it manually,but I don't want that

Comment: To clarify: Is it correct, that you're asking how the `date` column can contain an empty value instead of `0000-00-00 00:00:00`?

Comment: actually what I want when the status column or any other column changes datestamp changes, but if the status column is empty date column also empty

Comment: I put "checked" in "status" column.  until "checked" exists in status column timestamp changes, but if I remove "checked" from the status column date column will also empty

Comment: You need to use a trigger for that.

Comment: How to do that in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to change your column settings in your table. Go to the "Structure" of the table and change the column attributes to "on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP". You can easily do this through your cpanel phpmyadmin. Hope this helps!

Comment: I think you don't understand my question

Comment: Are you wanting the date column to remain blank if there is not a status update? If there is an update in the table do you want it to update the date in the database? I have a table set up with to date columns. One is a join date where the date they join is put in there and never changed. And then I have a last accessed column that every time they access the website the current timestamp is put into the last access column. Is the sounding closer to what you want?

Comment: Are you wanting the date column to go empty if the status column is empty? I think you are right I am not understanding your question

Comment: I think you are better off to Repose your question with more clarity.

Comment: date column is going empty if the status column is empty

Comment: Is that what you want it to do? Or what you are trying to avoid?

Comment: Everything is in front of you.actually what I want when the status column or any other column changes datestamp changes, but if the status column is empty date column also empty.I put "checked" in "status" column. until "checked" exists in status column timestamp changes, but if I remove "checked" from the status column date column will also empty

Comment: Here would be a good time and place to explain how you have fixed your problem. In doing this you will help others who have a similar situation to understand the problem and be able to resolve their issue as well. Glad you have it all fixed. Might I suggest that you compose your questions with more clarity as well as your answers. All that aside...  Congrats!

Comment: I am unable to add screenshots here. It will be more clear if I can upload screenshots.